# PHP: how to detect if youtube video is blocked on my website?

Tags: youtube-api

i have a music website that embed youtube videos,
in some of the videos i get this error:
"the video contains content from... who has blocked it from display on this website"
is there any way to check in PHP if the video is blocked on my website?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after i read some posts about this problem, i understand that i cant get the blacklist, so i found a dummy solution,
if the youtube cant play the video for any reason, i destroy the player and do whatever i want (show another player/video, or move the user to another page)

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data === -1) {
       // cant play the video, write here whatever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing how you do it. Did you ultimately find a "clean" solution or only the code above ? Is "-1" event never triggered on a normally working video? even on slow  speed networks?

Answer (score 2):

By checking for -1 in the onPlayerStateChange event, your code will fire whenever the player has any sort of error, not just when the content is restricted for embedded playback. A better way is to hook up the api's `onError` event and check for error codes 101 and 150 (they are the same). This will allow you to act differently in the case that other errors occur (bad request, html 5 issues, etc)

```
function onError(event){
    switch(event.data){
        case 2:
            console.log('request contains an invalid parameter value')
            break
        case 5:
            console.log('The requested content cannot be played in an HTML5 player or another error related to the HTML5 player has occurred.')
            break
        case 100:
            console.log('The video requested was not found. This error occurs when a video has been removed (for any reason) or has been marked as private.')
            break
        case 101:
        case 150:
            console.log('Uploader has blocked this content from embedded playback')
            break
        default:
            console.log('error code: '+event.data)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the YouTube API v3 to check this.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

Its two fold;

1: check if its been removed from YouTube and check if total results is > 0

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id&id=123456&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

2: check for access restrictions, if the total results > 0

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=123456&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Look for regionRestriction = blocked (with a country code being the same as yours)

More info on the API can be found here;

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Comment: thank you but its not a region restriction, its a website restriction, some youtube user blocked the embed on my website, so i want to detect it before the page load, any ideas?

Comment: In this case check 'status.embeddable' is set to true. The details for the API call are detailed here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos

Comment: i think you didnt understand me, the embed is available, but this one youtube user has disabled a spesific website, there is any way to check if my website is in the "blacklist"?